# reference request for Padovan number identity, comments on history

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, recurrence-relations

The Padovan numbers are defined as $P(0) = P(1) = P(2) = 1$ and $P(n) = P(n-2) + P(n-3)$ for $n \ge 3$.  The first few terms are $1,1,1,2,2,3,4,7,9,12$ (OEIS [A134816](https://oeis.org/A134816), [A000931](https://oeis.org/A000931)).  One of the identities given on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padovan_sequence) is
$$ \sum_{m=0}^n P(m)P(m+2) = P(n+2)P(n+3)-1$$
contributed by user Gandalf61 in July 2005.  Is there an earlier citation for this identity?  (Note that I'm not requesting a proof.)

Some notes on the history: The sequence was named by Ian Stewart in a 1996 *Scientific American* column citing the world of architecture, specifically Richard Padovan who credits Gérard Cordonnier and Hans van der Laan.  It arose earlier, without a particular name, in Thomas Green's 1968 "Recurrent sequences and Pascal's triangle" (*Math. Mag.* 41, 13-21) and Dov Jarden's 1966 *Recurring Sequences* with articles originally published in the late 1940s.  However, I did not see that any of these, or articles that cite them, include the identity given above.

Comment: same recursion, different start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perrin_number

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, closely related (like Fibonacci and Lucas), and those seem to satisfy $\sum_{m=0}^n R(m)R(m+2) = R(n+2)R(n+3)$.

Comment: Isn't the sum immediately telescoping?

Comment: @Somos Like many of the well-known Fibonacci identities, this is easy to prove.  This is a reference request.